# MTG: Blocking with multiple units

Tags: magic-the-gathering

New MTG player here and this is driving me nuts. How does the following work in magic the gathering?

Scenario 1: A player attacks with a 2/2 creature. The opposing player blocks with 3, 1/1 units. Do all 1/1 units die? Does the 2/2 also die? Do al 3, 1/1 units deal damage?

Scenario 2: A player attacks with a 2/2 creature. The opposing player blocks with 3, 1/2 units. Do all 1/2 units die? Does the 2/2 also die? Do al 3, 1/2 units deal damage?

Scenario 3: A player attacks with a 2/2 creature. The opposing player blocks with 3, 1/3 units. Do the 1/3 units survive? Does the 2/2 also die? Do al 3, 1/3 units deal damage?

Don't think about why you want to do this. I just want to know the rules for this :).

Comment: Have you read the ["Attacking and Blocking" section of "How to Play"](https://magic.wizards.com/en/how-to-play#attacking-blocking)?

Comment: https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/58347/what-happens-when-a-card-says-you-need-two-creatures-to-defend-an-attack Does this answer your question?

Comment: The brief answer is 1) two 1/1s die, 2/2 dies; 2) 1 1/2 dies, 2/2 dies; 3) all defenders survive, 2/2 dies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good thing to remember is that each creature deals total damage equal to its power. When an attacking creature is blocked by more than one creature, it deals its damage distributed as you choose among its blockers (note that it must assign lethal damage to each blocker before assigning damage to the next). Each blocking creature deals its damage to the attacker.

Remember: all damage is dealt at the same time!

To answer your scenarios:
**Scenario 1**: No more than two* 1/1 blocking creatures will die, and the 2/2 will die (it gets dealt 3 damage, 1 from each).
**Scenario 2**: Exactly one 1/2 blocker will die, and the 2/2 will also die.
**Scenario 3**: All 1/3 blockers will survive, because 2 damage is not lethal to any of them. The 2/2 also dies.

**Note that the attacking player may wish to assign all damage to first blocker, killing only one*

Comment: It's also worth noting that the attacking player chooses the order that the blocking creatures get dealt damage, so in scenario 1, for example, the attacker gets to choose which two of the blockers will die.

Comment: Attacker can also choose to kill only one 1/1 in scenario 1 (they can assign two damage to it, even though one damage is sufficient to make it die).